# Calculate $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{|z| = R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be an entire function and let $a$, $b \in \mathbb{C}$ with $a \neq b$.

1) Calculate $ \int_{|z| = R}  \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz$, if $R > |a|, |b|$.

2) Suppose $f$ is bounded and evaluate $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{|z| = R}  \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz$

For question (1) I used the fact that $ \int_{|z| = R}  \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz = \frac{1}{a-b}   (\int_{|z| = R}  \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz - \int_{|z| = R} \frac{f(z)}{z-b} dz ) \mbox{(partial fractions)}$, and then applied the Cauchy Integral formula to get that, $\frac{1}{a-b}   (\int_{|z| = R}  \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz - \int_{|z| = R} \frac{f(z)}{z-b} dz ) = 2\pi i \ \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$

Now I'm stuck at the second question because I've found the integral to not be dependent on $R$.

Comment: You should do the substitution $z = Re^{it}$ and let $R$ go to infinity.

Comment: The goal of this problem is to prove that a bounded, entire function is constant, so you will want to find some way of showing that the limit is zero.  Assume that $|f(z)|<M$, and use the fact that if $|z|>2\max(|a|,|b|)$, then $|(z-a)|>|z|/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|f(z)|<M$ for all $z$, and let $R>2\max(|a|,|b|)$.  Parameterize $|z|=R$ by $\gamma(t)=Re^{it}$.  Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}$.  Then if $|z|=R$, $|g(z)|<4M/R^2$.  Then

$$\left|\int_{\gamma} g(z)dz\right|=\left|\int_0^{2\pi} g(Re^{it})iRe^{it}dt\right|\leq \int_0^{2\pi} \left|g(Re^{it})iRe^{it}\right|dt\leq \int_0^{2\pi} (4M/R^2)R dt=\frac{8\pi M}{R}$$.

Since this value can be made arbitrarily small by taking large $R$, the limit must be zero.

---

It is worth combining the two parts.  On the one hand, the limit is zero.  On the other hand, it doesn't depend on $R$, and so is identically zero.  Thus, $f(a)=f(b)$.  Because $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, this implies that the function is constant.